# Aws Glue causing issue after reading array json file

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

We need to your assistance for the below AWS ETL Glue issue .

We are trying to read json files using AWS Glue dynamic frame .
Ex input json data :

```json
{"type":"TripLog","count":"2","def":["CreateTimestamp","UUID","DataTimestamp","VIN","DrivingRange","DrivingRangeUnit","FinishPos.Datum","FinishPos.Event","FinishPos.Lat","FinishPos.Lon","FinishPos.Odo","FinishPos.Time","FuelConsumption1Trip","FuelConsumption1TripUnit","FuelConsumptionTripA","FuelConsumptionTripAUnit","FuelUsed","FuelUsedUnit","Mileage","MileageUnit","ODOUnit","Score.AcclAdviceMsg","Score.AcclScore","Score.AcclScoreUnit","Score.BrakeAdviceMsg","Score.BrakeScore","Score.BrakeScoreUnit","Score.ClassJudge","Score.IdleAdviceMsg","Score.IdleScore","Score.IdleScoreUnit","Score.IdleStopTime","Score.LifetimeTotalScore","Score.TotalScore","Score.TotalScoreUnit","StartPos.Datum","StartPos.Lat","StartPos.Lon","StartPos.Odo","StartPos.Time","TripDate","TripId"],"data":[["2017-10-17 08:47:17.930","xxxxxxx","20171017084659"," xxxxxxxxxxx ","419","mile","WGS84","Periodic intervals during IG ON","38,16,39.846","-77,30,45.230","33559","20171017-033104","50.1","M-G - mph(U.S. gallon)","36.0","M-G - mph(U.S. gallon)","428.1","cm3",null,null,"km",null,null,"%",null,null,"%",null,null,null,"%","0x0",null,null,"%","WGS84","39,12,50.988","-76,38,36.417","33410","20171017-015103","20171017-015103","0"],["2017-10-17 08:47:17.930"," xxxxxxx ","20171017084659","xxxxxxxxxxx","414","mile","WGS84","Periodic intervals during IG ON","38,12,12.376","-77,29,57.915","33568","20171017-033604","50.1","M-G - mph(U.S. gallon)","36.0","M-G - mph(U.S. gallon)","838.0","cm3",null,null,"km",null,null,"%",null,null,"%",null,null,null,"%","0x0",null,null,"%","WGS84","39,12,50.988","-76,38,36.417","33410","20171017-015103","20171017-015103","0"]]}
```

Step 1): Code to read the json file to dynamic frame : * landing_location(Our file location)

```py
dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type = "s3",connection_options= {"paths": [landing_location], 'recurse':True, 'groupFiles': 'inPartition', 'groupSize': '1048576'},format = "json", transformation_ctx = "dyf")
dyf.printSchema()

root |-- type: string |-- count: string |-- def: array | |-- element: string |-- data: array | |-- element: array | | |-- element: choice | | | |-- int | | | |-- string
```

Step 2): Converting into spark data frame and exploding the data.

```
dtcadf = dyf.toDF()
dtcadf.show(truncate=False)
dtcadf.registerTempTable('dtcadf')
data=spark.sql('select explode(data) from dtcadf')
data.show(1,False)
```

Getting below issue :

> An error occurred while calling o270.showString.

Note : Same file we can able to succeed when we directly read the file using spark data frame instead of AWS Glue dynamic frame.

Can you please help me to resolve the issue ,And do let me know for further information from our end.